# What's wrong with this recursion (a fast power program）

Tags: haskell

I am a newbie for Haskell and is trying to calculate a^n where n is an integer.
It's OK! if I wrote

```
pow a n = if n==0 
    then 1
    else a * pow a (n-1)
```

However, when I wrote a quick implementation.

```
pow a n = if n==0 
    then 1
    else x*x*(if n rem 2==0 then 1 else a)
        where x = pow a (n quot 2)
```

The complier told me that

```
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        t2 ~ (a -> a -> a) -> t -> t2
      Expected type: p -> t2 -> p
        Actual type: p -> ((a -> a -> a) -> t -> t2) -> p
    • In the expression: pow a (n quot 2)
      In an equation for ‘x’: x = pow a (n quot 2)
      In an equation for ‘pow’:
          pow a n
            = if n == 0 then 1 else x * x * (if n rem 2 == 0 then 1 else a)
            where
                x = pow a (n quot 2)
    • Relevant bindings include
        n :: (a -> a -> a) -> t -> t2 (bound at pow.hs:1:7)
        pow :: p -> ((a -> a -> a) -> t -> t2) -> p (bound at pow.hs:1:1)
  |
4 |                 where x = pow a (n quot 2)
  |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: My haskell is pretty rusty, but I believe you need ``(n `quot` 2)``. You're trying to pass `quot` as an argument to `n` instead of using it as an infix operator with `n` and `2` as arguments.

Comment: Right, or `quot n 2`.

Comment: `n rem 2` calls function `n` with two arguments: `rem` and `2`. This is not what you want. Ditto for `n quot 2`.